# cardano-submit-api to allow local connections on LAN

Tags: cardano-submit-api

I have a cardano-node 1.34.0 and the associated cardano-submit-api running on a home server, for some reason I cannot get the cardano-submit-api to listen for incoming API calls.

> cardano-submit-api --socket-path /home/cardano/cnode/sockets/node.socket --port 6099 --config /home/cardano/cnode/config/tx-submit-mainnet-config.yaml --mainnet

results in the server apparently listening on the loopback 127.0.0.1

So to get it to listen for external connections I try:

> cardano-submit-api --socket-path /home/cardano/cnode/sockets/node.socket --listen-address 0.0.0.0 --port 6099 --config /home/cardano/cnode/config/tx-submit-mainnet-config.yaml --mainnet

Result:

> Mar 05 17:12:37 CARDANORELAY cardano-submit-api[46974]: [cardano-tx-submit:Info:12] [2022-03-05 17:12:37.65 UTC] Running server on 0.0.0.0:6099

Port scans from the LAN show no API port services available.  The servers firewall is disabled and no internal firewalls like UFW are operational, portscans show ports SSH, 3001, 8081 (Prometheus) etc as open, but not 6099.

Trying a transaction submit from Flint wallet just gives a server error, Flint custom server set to:

> http://192.168.111.107:6099/api/submit/tx

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Deeper port scans show TCP:6099 is open, not sure why that wasnt picking up before, so the server is actually listening.  Included a firewall rule and it seems the error may be on the Flint side, as no connection is being made to the cardano-submit-api server.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem was with Flint wallet, Nami does connect to the cardano-submit-api.

The need to do the detailed port scan had thrown me off the track.